# RxAndroid / RxLifeCycle - Handling dispose onError instead of onComplete

Tags: android, rx-java, android-lifecycle, rx-android

I'm currently trying to implement `RxLifeCycle` into my networking with `RxJava`. I've been using a subclass of `Consumer`, but for `RxLifeCycle`, you need to handle `onError`. So I have moved over to `Observer`.

The problem with this is that when the call is disposed, it's calling `onComplete` instead of `onError`, which I would prefer.

**buildle.gradle:**

```
 // RxJava
    compile 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:2.0.1'
    compile 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.0.3'
    compile 'com.trello.rxlifecycle2:rxlifecycle-kotlin:2.2.1'
    compile 'com.trello.rxlifecycle2:rxlifecycle-android-lifecycle-kotlin:2.2.1'
```

My previous `NetworkConsumer` was structured like this, and I would handle all the results in `accept`.

**NetworkConsumer:**

```
abstract class NetworkConsumer<T> : Consumer<NetworkResponse<T>> {

    @Throws(Exception::class)
    override fun accept(response: NetworkResponse<T>) {
         ...
    }

    // to override
    open fun onSuccess(response: T) {}
    open fun onComplete() {}


}
```

My network calls are all structured the same way using `Single`.

```
fun getFavorites(): Single<NetworkResponse<Array<MyObject>>>
```

And I'm using it like this.

```
service.getFavorites(...)
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribe(object : NetworkConsumer<Array<MyObject>>() {
                    override fun onSuccess(response: Array<MyObject>) {
                         // use response
                    }

                    override fun onComplete() {
                         // do whatever, like hiding the loading view.
                         loading_view.visibility = View.GONE
                    }
 })
```

I really like this setup as it allows me to move a lot of the logic from the calling `Activity` into the `NetworkConsumer` and only worry about handling the result.

However, with `RxLifeCycle`, you need to use an `Observable` instead of a `Single`. So I created a `NetworkObserver` to handle this change.

**NetworkObserver:**

```
abstract class NetworkObserver<T> : Observer<NetworkResponse<T>> {

    override fun onSubscribe(d: Disposable) {}

    override fun onNext(response: NetworkResponse<T>) {}

    override fun onError(e: Throwable) {}

    override fun onComplete() {}

   // other functions from NetworkConsumer
}
```

However, the problem is that `onComplete` is being called when the network call is disposed, which I would prefer to handle any UI changes in `onComplete` instead.

For example, I'm showing a loading screen when the network call is started, and I want to hide that loading screen when it's done, regardless if it failed or didn't.

I believe I just need to use a different Class instead of `Observer` for this, but I'm unsure which Class would work best for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct answer is `SingleObserver`, this is perfect for networking.

```
abstract class NetworkObserver<T> : SingleObserver<NetworkResponse<T>> {

    override fun onSubscribe(d: Disposable) {
        ...
    }

    override fun onSuccess(response: NetworkResponse<T>) {
        ... handle onSuccess
    }

    override fun onError(e: Throwable) {
        ... cancelled or an error
    }
}
```